# Looking for example of Javapackager gradle integration for a JavaFX app

Tags: gradle, javafx

I am looking for the most sensible way to integrate packaging of a JavaFX application into my Gradle build.

The plugin at https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle does not look like it's maintained and I was wondering if there was a better way than manually hacking together a command line invocation of javapackager where I have to manually resolve all the dependency stuff myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing similar situations, so I started a pure gradle sample project on github

https://github.com/moxi/javafx-gradle-multiproject-setup

I'll try to update that code with basic stuff like generating the Dmg for Mac apps, for now it's good as a starter.

You're right the plugin you were looking is no longer supported, as you can see in the last comment the author posted of this issue:

https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle/issues/49/documentation-and-a-working-sample

I found the following project and it's kinda working, it needs some tweaks for a multiple modules project, however it generates the binaries correctly:

https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin

This guy seems to be active on the project nowadays, the lack of documentation is an issue but still you can deploy your JavaFX project, I tried creating a DMG package for Mac, you will have to try the same thing with the platforms you're planning to support.

Answer (score -1):

You can look at this blog:

- [**Build a JavaFX + LeapMotion application with gradle**](http://thierrywasyl.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/build-a-javafx-leapmotion-application-with-gradle/)

I've been meaning to convert a couple of JavaFX projects following this outline.  I keep thinking I'd like a LeapMotion box :-)

It should get you started.  As far as I can tell you need to use the JavaPackager to build a '*correct*' JavaFX app.  That's the magic that set-up a Platform thread and other behind the scenes stuff (*npi*).